# When does a person with replacement synthetic body parts lose their consciousness and become a machine?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, trans-humanism, consciousness

What I’m trying to figure out is if your body is replaced with synthetic parts (my civilization has the technology to do that as well as bioengineering and cloning technology), at what point do you become no longer you. Obviously machine prosthetics don’t delete someone’s identity, consciousness, soul, etc. So where is the line where one’s consciousness, soul, etc. are lost and you’re only left with a machine?  Could someone end up having a completely synthetic body and still retain their soul, consciousness, and self? Or would the machine eventually entirely take over, only imitating the original person like a behavioral zombie?

To make this question more clear, I will try to explain how my story world defines soul and consciousness. My approach is somewhat comparable to Tolkien’s in his Legendarium. In my story universe, the universe and everything in it has been created by a being known to humanity as the Creator. The Creator gives everyone a soul and consciousness.  My story universe is like a block universe, where all of time already exists concurrently. So a person’s soul/consciousness has always existed since the creation of the Block Universe.

Let me define my terms to help clarify my question:  The *soul* I consider to be what makes you *you* and not someone else or something else.  Essentially, the soul should be considered as *self* or the unique combination of elements that makes you who you are.

I think a self is made of the following things:

- Memories
- Thought patterns (the way an individual mind processes information/thinks about things)
- Likes, dislikes, preferences.
- Moral agency (the ability to make decisions based on whether they are morally right or wrong).  In other words, persons are moral and ethical agents endowed with a conscience.
- Creative skills in form of artwork, technology, imagination, etc.

In my story world, the relationship between soul (self) and body can be described in terms like Tolkien’s view: the body is like a dwelling, and the soul (self) is like an indweller.  When the person dies, the soul lives on in another dimension.

So what I need to know is whether the replacing of the biological body with a synthetic one would result in the person’s death, hence separation of the person’s soul from the body.  Would the complete synthesization of the body result in a different self/soul arising within the synthetic body and the death/loss of the original self/soul, or would the original self/soul be preserved?

I hope this clarification helps.

Comment: **Social worldbuilding has always been a difficult ride on this Stack** And I speak from experience, because I'm frequently one of the people who vote to close soft-science quesitons as too story-based. The problem is often one of lack of confidence. Do you want me to tell you the rule for your world? Because I feel like that's what you've asked me to do. So, if you'll forgive me, I'm going to answer your question twice. Once to address your issue &mdash; then again to help you see why I'm rarely a fan of social or cultural worldbuilding without having a definitive, objective, and specific que

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145413/discussion-on-question-by-kal-madda-when-does-a-person-with-replacement-syntheti); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: @L.Dutch I'm not sure you did anyone a favor by deleting my answer and converting the first paragraph to an incomplete comment. I actually answered his question, too.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "soul" and what constitutes keeping or losing it in your world - as it's a bit of a fuzzy concept to say the least. It seems like a writing decision as to where the line is drawn - unless you can give us a clear set of metrics for "soul".

Comment: @AngryMuppet  I edited my question to clarify what I mean by soul.

Comment: OK, but how is it *measured*? (the "metrics" I referred to) What would make you only half you as opposed to 0.6 you?

Comment: @AngryMuppet  I don’t believe there’s any such thing as half you (at least not that makes any rational sense to me), there’s either you or not you.

Comment: Then we have no means to answer except with opinions. Leaving closed at present.

Comment: @AngryMuppet I can give you my metrics for what I consider a soul (I just don’t believe there’s such a thing as a half a you).  I think your memories and your thought patterns are what constitutes your soul.  It defines the way you think and the way you experience things.

Comment: Please give us something to go on, what sort of answer are you looking for for the question. Remember we need definite criteria to point to a "best answer" built into the question. At the moment there's nothing but undefined parameters and no way  of telling what constitutes a best answer as far as I can see (lack of reopen votes would seem to support that position).

Comment: @AngryMuppet I will try to add more to the question for you.  I don’t want to draw out the comments here, so I’ll try to add the things you’re asking for in the question.

Comment: @AngryMuppet I edited my question and included metrics I believe can be used to “measure” self.  Thank you for the advice, hopefully my clarification helps.

Comment: OK. So all a computer has to do is report that it feels like itself and enjoys jam doughnuts like a person, emulate the thoughts of a person (as people practice in writing classes) and have access to the complete personal record of someone in order to pass as that person. Not clear how that helps, can you clarify by offering something measurable, quantifiable by something other than self-reporting or emulation? You see, it's not as if there is a definitive test for psychosis even in humans today.

Comment: This question asks the age-old "Ship of Theseus" connundrum. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus It doesn't matter that the original parts are being replaced with artificial ones. From a cybernetic perspective, the only part that matters is the frontal lobe. Everything else is mechanism. Even if you did "replace" that by uploading it to an equivalent machine, equivalence specifically states that it's not meaningfully different, therefore the person is the same person. This makes this little more than a novel rephrasing.

Comment: @RobertRapplean  If I understand what you’re saying correctly, then you’re saying that the synthetic body will still be the same person, correct?  I’d consider this to be a potential answer to my question.

Comment: My response is that this is a deep philosophical question. Its answer depends on what you believe is the essential kernel of a person. If you duplicate a person, atom by atom, is the duplicate the same person as the original? Even if the original still exists? Rationally, a person is the sum of their knowledge, and the perspective on that knowledge. Socially, a person is whoever we think they are. These two are not intrinsically tied, so you get to pick.

Comment: How much meat do you need to add to a robot before it grows a soul?

Comment: Voted to reopen. Seems like we're getting a lot of "answers as comments" which shows me that it doesn't seem to lack focus so much that it's a problem for this question.

Comment: @JamieB Thanks, I appreciate it! . I’ve tried to clarify it as much as possible to make it easier for people to be able to answer.  I hope my edits have clarified what I’m asking.  I have to admit that my original version of my question was likely not clear enough, so confused people as to what I was asking for.

Comment: In my latest book, Dystopia: Clempson Goes to Hell, the citizens of Hell have serial immortality. At the point of death, the connectome is recorded and built into a new clone. They consider the reincarnation to be the same person. Society also considers the person to be more of the same. God (and, yes, he exists in this world), on the other hand, doesn't. Once the original life ceases, that person is no longer God's responsibility or problem. Constructs, even identical biological ones, don't count. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @RobertRapplean Maybe.  I am thinking about having a character who has lived thousands of years by turning his physical body into a synthetic one, and I was hoping I could figure out from a scientific perspective from what we at least “think we know”, whether or not that soul/self could actually be housed within a synthetic body, or whether the removal of the original biological body would mark the death of the individual, hence the separation of the said soul from the synthetic body, only leaving a synthetic being who acts as a behavioral zombie of the original.

Comment: Ah, here we get to the meat of it, literally. The thing that makes us people instead of automatons is that we aren't rational entities. We constantly have to balance our goals with our emotions. Just being able to control the flow of the hormones would significantly change our personality, and their complete elimination would severely change our perspective. Such things can be simulated, of course, but that's just a configuration setting.

Comment: everything you define as soul can be modified by hormones and brain traumata. i see no place for anything which would persist through the ultimate trauma of death.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jamie B pointed out, there is apparently enough of this question to warrant a full answer. Someone should un-delete JBH's answer.

The OP asked a question that is basically a [Ship of Theseus paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus). You can summarize the paradox as *If you replace all of the parts, one part at a time, when does it stop being the original thing and become something else?*

There are numerous [conundrums that address this in fiction.](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheseusShipParadox) The most prominent is the Star Trek Transporter issue. If you destroy someone here and recreate them there, does the soul get transferred to the new body? If you have a transporter accident and create two of someone, do they split the soul between them? Without a way to measure souls, that one is unanswerable.

Later in the conversation stream, this morphed into a more complex question. Something like *When you replace parts of a person with cybernetic parts, when does it stop being the same person?*

This is a deeper question because you have to ask how close you have to get to the original for it to be the same person. We are a slightly different person every time we change our minds. Significant brain damage can make us a completely different person, even though they remain the same legal entity.

There also seems to be more than a hint at the question *At what point do they stop being human?* This is a substantially different question because, in some universes, machines are people, too.

There are a multitude of factors that contribute to who we are. One thing that distinguishes humans from machines is that we have to constantly balance our rational processes with our emotional, chemical, biological side. If you stripped a person of all hormones, then they probably wouldn't be the same person.

They also wouldn't know when they were hungry or tired. They wouldn't make emotional connections, and action prioritization would become more effort that it was worth. This is an unescapable reality that has been demonstrated by studying what happens to those who suffer brain trauma.

#### So, let's draw lines in the sand.

- A person stops being human when they no longer have human motivations. As inhuman as people can get when responding to the need for sex or the need for power, it's their response that we consider inhuman, not the urges.
- A person stops being themselves when you have a discontinuity of mental processes. The Ship of Theseus continues to be the same ship, even if you replace all of the parts. If you completely disassemble the ship, then re-assemble it, it is a reproduction from the same parts. My answer, my rules. If you don't like it, write something different.

#### Alternately, duck typing

If it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck, then it is a duck. A person is their thoughts, experiences, and intent. As long as the mind-states are preserved, and the mind-states operate on an equivalent substrate, then it is the same person. No philosophical questions asked.

If you duplicate a person, then they are all instances of the same person, with new identity being accumulated as soon as the duplicates start having independent experiences.

#### The Keel and the Illusion of Mind

For most "things," there is a central part that is more important than all of the other parts. For a ship, it's probably the keel. If you want to go by those rules, anything built on that keel can be considered the same ship.

Humans have the prefrontal cortex. You can shave bits off of the prefrontal cortex, but such will change a person in ways that you can't always call them the same person. [Phineas Gage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phineas_Gage) had a spike put through his head, was he the same person? Legally, someone who suffers brain damage is physically the same person, but that's not what OP asked. We specifically gave frontal lobotomies because we wanted the person to become a different person.

We've looked for centuries for the one part of the brain that is the seat of our consciousness, and it doesn't get any smaller than this. Those who have strokes and suffer brain damage in those areas usually become a shadow of their former selves. The concept of brain plasticity doesn't apply when you carve out a chunk of someone's reasoning power.

#### No universal solution

When it comes down to it, there is no one right answer. In the universe of The Fermi Project, the citizens of Hell have serial immortality. When their body is destroyed, they can make a new one and build their old body's connectome into it. They think that they are the same person as the original, and society believes that they are. God, however (yes, one exists in my world), feels that discontinuity of consciousness basically voids the warranty. These new, thinking bodies aren't his problem any more than a thinking machine would be.

Comment: Unfortunately, someone is one of the Mods. When they delete something, they're the only people who can undelete it. But thanks for the confidence, it's appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Organic (humans, human-like) beings are machines. The machines just use proteins and fluids. Brains made out of meat are little different... they seem to be implemented in a peculiar kind of computing system called neural networks. We've recently had some success implementing those in silicon.

And the results are interesting. Read the news if you want details there.

Could a metal machine, with silicon for a brain be conscious in the way we are? Likely, though it's still highly speculative how much computing power (or even what type) would be necessary. And the software for such a conscious robot can't even be guessed at yet. Not by intelligent people.

So, replacing meat parts with prosthetics won't necessarily cause someone to turn into some sort of p-zombie. Even brain prosthetics aren't ruled out. Keep in mind that *crude* brain prosthetics might well turn someone into a vegetable (free advice: don't accept $75 to let Elon Musk's brain transistor project experiment on your skull).

Without being mean, consider that your question has an inverse that illustrates the absurdity of your query: How much meat do you have to add to a robot before it grows a soul?